# How to query without using Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

I have these few tables:

issues
1. id
2. name

tags
1. id
2. name

issue_tag
1. issue_id
2. tag_id

images
1. id 
2. url 
3. issue_id

The relationship of these tables is stated below:

- Issue hasMany Images, Images belongsTo Issue
- Issues belongsToMany Tags, Tags belongsToMany Issues

How can I retrieve all the records by **NOT USING ELOQUENT**, just by using the **QUERY BUILDER**. I would like to retrieve the data in the format like:

```
[
  {
    id: issue_id,
    name: issue_name,
    tags: [
            {
              id: tag_id_1,
              name: tag_name_1
            },
            {
              id: tag_id_2,
              name: tag_name_2
            }
          ]
  },
  {
   ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Please someone help me because I could not solve this problem for a long time, I can only solve it by using Eloquent. But using Eloquent is not a solution for me.

Comment: You can't use relationships without Eloquent. If you don't want to use the ORM, you're better off writing the entire thing using raw query.

Comment: If I would like to use `DB::table('issues')` method, how should I joins the table?

Comment: See this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

Comment: This is how you write raw statements, btw: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use join query. For Details follow this link [demo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)

Or
Use DB:: statement ('your raw query here'). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use can Laravel DB::select(); function
With the use of select, we can pass Raw SQL query into select

```
 $innerData = [];
    $issueAll =  DB::select('select i.id,i.name,i2.url as image,t.id as tag_id,
                            t.name as tag_name,it.issue_id from issues as i
                            inner join issue_tag as it on it.issue_id=i.id
                            inner join tags as t on it.tag_id = t.id
                            inner join images as i2 on i.id = i2.issue_id
                            ');
    foreach ($issueAll as $issue) {
        $innerData[$issue->id]["id"] = $issue->id;
        $innerData[$issue->id]["name"] = $issue->name;
        if (isset($innerData[$issue->id]['tags'][$issue->issue_id])) {
            array_push($innerData[$issue->id]['tags'], ['id'=>$issue->tag_id, 'name'=>$issue->tag_name]);
        } else {
            $innerData[$issue->id]['tags'][$issue->issue_id] = ['id'=>$issue->tag_id, 'name'=>$issue->tag_name];
        }
    }
    return $innerData;
```

The response you get

```
{ 
   "1":{ 
      "id":1,
      "name":"issue1",
      "tags":{ 
         "1":{ 
            "id":1,
            "name":"tag1"
         },
         "2":{ 
            "id":1,
            "name":"tag1"
         }
      }
   },
   "2":{ 
      "id":2,
      "name":"issue2",
      "tags":{ 
         "2":{ 
            "id":1,
            "name":"tag1"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel if you don't want to use eloquent then you can use with DB::statement('your query') and don't forget to use USE DB; at the top of the file